# How to call Fortran routine with unit number argument from C

Tags: c, io, fortran, shared-libraries, abi

If I have a Fortran subroutine which takes a Fortran IO Unit as one of its parameters (for printing debug information to), and this function is compiled into a shared library, how do I correctly call this function from C?

```
! An example subroutine that I want to call from C:
subroutine hi(unit)
    integer :: unit
    write(unit,*) "hello"
end subroutine

! example call site in Fortran
program main
    call hi(6)
end
```

I am interested in how these unit numbers relate to file descriptors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely compiler dependent, there is no portable correspondence. See the manual of your compiler if they support some sort of interoperability as an extension.

Comment: Do you have an example or reference for any compiler? The gfortran docs do not mention this issue.

Comment: There is no connection whatsoever and don't even think of trying to create one. C and Fortran don't share I/O systems and Fortran unit numbers do not correspond to C file descriptors. The Fortran I/O system may (or may not) use C I/O underneath, but that's not helpful to you. You should do all your I/O from one language - have callbacks into that language if needed.

Comment: @user2664470 If the manual does not cover this, then there is no option. The language standard certainly does not support any interoperability in this case. I agree with Steve Lionel that you should operate the file from only one language.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FNUM.html Note that this is the POSIX file descriptor; Gfortran doesn't use C stdio so there is no way to return a corresponding stdio stream (posix has fdopen so you could create one from the fd)

Comment: @janneb also note that is a GNU extension and not standard Fortran.

Comment: ...That being said, mixing io from different runtimes to the same file is a recipe for trouble, so avoid it if at all possible.